# "A vicious monster (now) stalks you from the shadows"

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a description for a game and I'm not sure which of these sentences is grammatically correct. Just to add some context, you are a prisoner who must now escape prison because there is a monster on the loose.

> Version 1: As if breaking out of prison wasn't hard enough, a vicious
>   monster stalks you from the shadows.
>
> Version 2: As if breaking out of prison wasn't hard enough, a vicious
>   monster **now** stalks you from the shadows.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Is there any difference between the two in terms of their meaning?

Comment: I decided to post an answer instead of my (now deleted) comments, but the only supporting evidence I can offer is my expertise as a native speaker and writer. I'd be happy to withdraw it if someone can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate the context? One must escape from the prison because the monster is _in_ the prison? Or is it on the loose in the outside world?

Comment: I have a question in return. I've noticed a lot of uniformity in syntax among dungeon masters in their game descriptions. I'm wondering if D&D, Pathfinder, etc. manuals give example text whose syntax is cribbed/unconsciously absorbed by DMs... Any input Matthew Shaile?

Comment: @alwayslearning The monster is inside the prison

For more context, here is the entire description paragraph:
"You are awoken in your prison cell by blood-curdling screams. You gotta get out of here. As if breaking out of prison wasn't hard enough, a vicious monster **[now?]** stalks you from the shadows. In order to survive you must use your intelligence, resourcefulness and just the right amount of violence!"

Comment: @Silenus It's not for D&D or Pathfinder, it's for a video game (a point & click adventure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a matter of grammar, as both sentences are correct. But the second sentence sounds better:

> Version 2: "As if breaking out of prison wasn't hard enough, a vicious
>   monster now stalks you from the shadows."

Both sentences convey the same general meaning, but using *now* really emphasises the sense of ongoing struggle - "first this, now that".

Answer (score 1):

They have slightly different meanings, IMO.

The first says that the stalking monster is currently stalking you (and may have been stalking you for some time), and is likely to cause you a problem very soon indeed.

The second says that the stalking monster has only just started to stalk you, and so you may have a few moments before it becomes an immediate problem.